# How to make 10 combinations of 4-letter words out of 20 letter pairs

Tags: algorithm

Please forgive the verbose text. This is a complex problem and I have tried a many solutions. Unfortunately, I can't predict what information anyone will need to assist me, so I have tried to include as much as I can.

Given an array of 20 letter pairs:

```
['BA', 'BO', 'CO', 'CR', 'DA','FA', 'FE', 'FI', 'GL', 'LL','MA', 'NE', 'OW', 'OW', 'RE','RK', 'RN', 'SK', 'ST', 'TS']
```

A `letter pair` can appear more than once in the `letter pairs` array.

And an array of `4-letter words`:

```
['BALL','BANE','BARE','BARK','BARN','BASK','BAST','BATS','BOLL','BONE','BORE','BORK','BORN','BOSK','BOTS','CODA','COMA','CONE','CORE','CORK','CORN','COST','COTS','CROW','DARE','DARK','DARN','FALL','FANE','FARE','FAST','FATS','FELL','FERE','FERN','FEST','FETS','FICO','FIFE','FILL','FINE','FIRE','FIRN','FIST','FITS','GLOW','MALL','MANE','MARE','MARK','MASK','MAST','MATS','NEMA','NEST','NETS','REST','RETS','STOW']
```

The number of `4-letter words` can vary, but will normally be less than 100. Also, they have been filtered out of a dictionary to ensure that each half of the `4-letter word` will match a `letter pair`. A `letter pair` can only be used in a single combination as many times as it appears in the `letter-pair` array.

I would like to generate all valid combinations. Each combination should contain 10 unique `4-letter words` which exist in the `4-letter words` array. But each of the 10 entries in each combination is created by concatenating two `letter pairs` together to form a string. For example: CO and RK go together make CORK. BA and TS go together to make BATS.

Here is an example of a valid combination:

```
[
    [
    'BATS',
    'BONE',
    'CORN',
    'CROW',
    'DARK',
    'FALL',
    'FIFE',
    'GLOW',
    'MASK',
    'REST'
    ],
    [/** more combinations **/],
]
```

I created a pointer class that essentially generates combinations on-the-fly (I will happily post the code on request, but since it's not suited to my purpose, I omitted it).

So far, all solutions I could come up with either take days to run or consume too much memory, so the solution needs to be fast and memory-efficient.

Considering we know that (according to the `4-letter words` array) certain pairs can not appear together in a certain order, this should reduce the number of possibilities drastically. For example, GL and CR can't appear together because they don't make a word.

Can anyone suggest an fast and efficient way of doing this? In my mind, I should be able to produce all combinations within seconds or minutes if done intelligently, perhaps using some kind of tree structure and elimination. Normally I excel at these kinds of problems, but this one has been baffling me for weeks. Also, I can't help thinking that this may have already been solved before.

**TL;DR**: Match the letter pairs to make 10 different four-letter words by using two letter pairs for each word to make a valid combination. Each letter pair must be used once and only once per combination. This solution needs to intelligent, as brute forcing from either the 4-letter words side or the 20 letter pairs side takes around 80-100 hours.

I would like to generate all valid combinations, but without 62,828,356,305 iterations to find every possible combination with the 4-letter words array, and without 670,442,572,800 iterations to find every possible combination with the letter-pairs array.

EDIT: Corrected a typo, where I said 4-letter word array and meant to say letter-pairs array. Sorry @Nick

Comment: What is your current time and space complexity? Also which approach are you using? Since reading the question i can think of dfs approach maybe. Also is it a fixed given size of both arrays?

Comment: Reverse the problem. Split the four letter words into their two letter pairs and create a trie.

Comment: also when you say `I would like to generate all valid combinations. Each combination should contain 10 unique 4-letter words` do you mean there can be multiple output arrays?

Comment: Your question is too verbose and unclear. Can you narrow it down to inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: 1. Using [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) will efficiently iterate the combinations with virtually no memory footprint. 2. Load the dictionary into an efficient data structure like a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for more efficient lookups. 3. "Rules for pairs that don't go together" is really just the _inverse of the dictionary_ which would arguably be even less efficient to query since it it's likely to have an order of magnitude more entries.

Comment: @Sammitch just asking for clarifications to up my knowledge. Doesn't Trie have a preprocessing overhead? What if the dataset is small? Is it worth on a small dataset?

Comment: "Small" and "worth it" are relative quantities that I can't comment on. But the Trie must be pre-computed and it's up to you to determine at what point it's "worth" it for faster lookups. A simpler binary search is also an option, but I'm assuming that your dictionary is probably the 4-letter subset of the _literal dictionary_.

Comment: I think I understand the question. Firstly, I believe we can assume all of the give four-letter words are comprised of pairs from the given two-letter words. Now suppose that, instead each "combination" being comprised of 10 four-letter words, it is to be comprised of 3 four-lettter words. Then `["MARK", "MALL", "STOW"]` is not a valid combination because "MARK" and "MALL" both require the two-letter word "MA" but the list of two letter words contains only one "MA"...

Comment: ...Now suppose there are two additions to the four-letter words, "CROW" and "GLOW". Then neither is `["STOW", "CROW", "GLOW"]` a valid combination because three "OW"s are required but there are only two in the list of two letter words. If my understanding is correct I suggest you say that each 10-word combination is formed by sampling 20 two-letter words *without replacement*....

Comment: ...In other words to check if a combination of 10 four-letter words is valid one considers each word in turn, removing from the list of two-letter words the two words that form the given word. If this can be done for all 10 words in the combination is valid. If, however, one or both of the two-letter words needed to form a word in the 10-word combination is/are missing from the two-word list, the combinations is invalid. It would be horribly inefficient, but you could of course generate all 10-word combinations and throw out those that are invalid.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not sure your interpretation is correct, I think that if the 4-letter words are `["STOW", "CROW", "GLOW"]` then you can use `OW` 3 times in a combination since it occurs 3 times in that list. Based on "A letter pair can only be used in a single combination as many times as it appears in the 4-letter word array"

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. Yes, I'm guessing about what is needed here, believing the OP may have meant "...as it appears in the 2-letter word array". Why else would `"OW"` appear twice in the 2-letter word array? Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: I quickly read the comments so I might skipped it.. If you have access to a dictionary, can't you get all 4 letter words starting with two letters. Then get each last two letters to see if they exist in the array?

Comment: fuzzy, I would like to offer a solution if my understanding of the question--as I stated in comments above--is correct. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland From what I can see, your interpretation of the problem is spot on. Each letter-pair must be used exactly once in a valid combination. And the same pair of letters can (but most often won't) appear more than once in the letter-pairs array.

Comment: @Adi As mentioned, I would like to be able to achieve this in seconds or minutes with minimal RAM usage. I believe the current "brute-force" methods that I have been using, will never give me the results I want, as it's always a trade off between CPU time and memory. Every brute-forcing method I have tried, either eats up my 2GB of RAM in seconds, or suggest that the script will need to run for days to find all possible combinations. I would like, if possible, to find every possible combination of 10 words that satisfies my requirements above.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @leitning I tried this out a few days ago, but I had no idea how to make it work. However, I do genuinely believe that this may be the key to solving my problem -- if I can figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm sorry, but as far as I know the information is already in the original post and it's already been classified as too verbose and unfocused by at least one person. To me, it's clear, but I suspect that may just be because I've been working on it for so long. Unfortunately, it's a surprisingly complex problem and it's difficult to convey what I have and haven't done without writing a book. However, if you have any specific suggestions, I will gladly modify the original post.

Comment: What is the typical size of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given:

- a hash `counts` whose keys are two-letter strings and whose values are positive integers that indicate the number of times the key can be used to form the first two or last two characters of a four-letter string, denoted the *prefix* and *suffix*;
- a set `fours` containing four-character strings, each string comprised of the concatenation of a two-character prefix `p` and a two-character suffix `s` such that `p` and `s` are both keys of `counts` and:

  - if `p == s`, `counts[p] >= 2`; else
  - `counts` has keys `p` and `s`.
- a positive integer `n` which equals the size of subsets of `fours` to be constructed, denoted *combinations*.

For a given combination let `g` be a hash whose keys equal two-digit strings that appear as a prefix or suffix in at least one of the words in the combination and whose values, `g[t]`, equal the number prefixes and suffixes among words in the combination that equal `t`. A combination is *valid* if `g[t] <= counts[t]`, for all keys `t` of `g`.

The objective is to generate all valid combinations for a given `counts`, `fours` and `n`.

Note that since `counts` is a hash its keys are unique and since `fours` is a set its elements are unique.

---

I will generate the valid combinations recursively. The following code is in Ruby but it generally can be read as pseudo-code.

```
def enumerate_tail(n, counts, fours, fours_selected = [], fours_offset = 0)
  # n is number elements that must be added to four_selected
  # counts is original counts with values reduced each time word is added to fours_selected
  # fours[fours_offset] is word currently considered for appending to fours_selected

  # First case is when fours[fours_offset] is not selected 
  # This requires there to be at least n elements remaining in fours
  if fours.size - fours_offset -1 >= n 
    enumerate_tail(n, counts, fours, fours_selected, fours_offset+1)
  end
  
  # Now consider case where fours[fours_offset] is selected if that is possible
  four = fours[fours_offset]
  p = four[0,2] # first 2 chars
  s = four[2,2] # last 2 chars

  return unless (counts[p] > 0 && counts[s] >= 0)

  # Consider case where addition of fours[fours_offset] creates combination 
  if n == 1
    $combinations << (fours_selected + [fours_offset])
  else
    enumerate_tail(n-1, counts.merge(p=>counts[p]-1, s=>counts[s]-1),
      fours, fours_selected + [fours_offset], fours_offset+1)
  end
end
```

---

Let's try it.

```
counts = ['BA', 'BO', 'CO', 'CR', 'DA','FA', 'FE', 'FI', 'GL', 'LL','MA',
          'NE', 'OW', 'OW', 'RE','RK', 'RN', 'SK', 'ST', 'TS'].tally​
  #=> {"BA"=>1, "BO"=>1, "CO"=>1, "CR"=>1, "DA"=>1, "FA"=>1, "FE"=>1,
  #    "FI"=>1, "GL"=>1, "LL"=>1, "MA"=>1, "NE"=>1, "OW"=>2, "RE"=>1,
  #    "RK"=>1, "RN"=>1, "SK"=>1, "ST"=>1, "TS"=>1}
```

```
fours = [
  "BALL", "BANE", "BARE", "BARK", "BARN", "BASK", "BAST", "BATS", "BOLL",
  "BONE", "BORE", "BORK", "BORN", "BOSK", "BOTS", "CODA", "COMA", "CONE",
  "CORE", "CORK", "CORN", "COST", "COTS", "CROW", "DARE", "DARK", "DARN",
  "FALL", "FANE", "FARE", "FAST", "FATS", "FELL", "FERE", "FERN", "FEST",
  "FETS", "FICO", "FIFE", "FILL", "FINE", "FIRE", "FIRN", "FIST", "FITS",
  "GLOW", "MALL", "MANE", "MARE", "MARK", "MASK", "MAST", "MATS", "NEMA",
  "NEST", "NETS", "REST", "RETS", "STOW"
]
```

```
n = 10
```

---

The valid combinations will be held in a global variable that must be initialized to an empty array:

```
$combinations = []
```

We can generate the combinations by executing `enumerate_tail` with its arguments `fours_selected` and `fours_offset` assigned to their default values of an empty array and zero, respectively.

```
enumerate_tail(n, counts, fours)
```

---

This took 121 seconds to execute on an M2 Macbook Air. The number of combinations generated is given by:

```
$combinations.size
  #=> 6,812,925
```

By contrast, as `fours.size #=> 59`, the total number of combinations of size `10`, without reference to `counts`, equals:

```
59!/(10!*49!)
  #=> 62,828,356,305
```

---

Consider the first combination of `10` generated:

```
arr = $combinations[0]
  #=> [23, 26, 31, 34, 39, 45, 50, 53, 57, 58]
```

Recall these are offsets into `fours`. The corresponding values from `fours` equals:

```
fours.values_at(*arr)
  #=> ["CROW", "DARN", "FATS", "FERN", "FILL",
  #    "GLOW", "MASK", "NEMA", "RETS", "STOW"]
```

---

Below is the method with `puts` statements inserted to display intermediate calculations. Readers familiar with Ruby can use this with more restrictive values of `counts` and `fours`, and smaller `n`, to better understand the recursion. It is necessary to initialize two global variables (other than `$combinations`) before executing the method: `$debug = true` and `$i = 0`.

```
def enumerate_tail(n, counts, fours, fours_selected = [], fours_offset = 0)
  # n is number elements that must be added to four_selected
  # counts is original counts with values reduced each time word is added to fours_selected
  # fours[fours_offset] is word currently considered for appending to fours_selected

if $debug
  $i += 1
  puts "\nEntered enumerate_tail with $i = #{$i}, n = #{n}"
  puts "  counts = #{counts}"
  puts "  fours_selected = #{fours_selected}"
  puts "  fours_offset = #{fours_offset}, fours[#{fours_offset}] = #{fours[fours_offset]}"
      
  # First case is when fours[fours_offset] is not selected 
  # This requires there to be at least n elements remaining in fours

  puts "Insuffient size of remaining fours to not select fours[#{fours_offset}] = #{fours[fours_offset]}" if fours.size - fours_offset -1 < n
end  
  if fours.size - fours_offset -1 >= n 
if $debug    
    puts "Case of not selecting fours[#{fours_offset}] = #{fours[fours_offset]}"
    puts "calling enumerate_tail with n = #{n}, fours_selected = #{fours_selected}, fours offset = #{fours_offset+1}"
end
    enumerate_tail(n, counts, fours, fours_selected, fours_offset+1)
if $debug    
    puts "\nBack in $i = #{$i}"
end
  end
  
  # Now consider case where fours[fours_offset] is selected if that is possible
  four = fours[fours_offset]
  p = four[0,2] # first 2 chars
  s = four[2,2] # last 2 chars
if $debug    
  puts "four = #{four}, counts[#{p}] = #{counts[p]}, counts[#{s}] = #{counts[s]}"
  puts "Returning as at counts[#{p}] or counts[#{s}] is zero" if (counts[p].zero? || counts[s].zero?)
end  
  #i -= 1 if (counts[p].zero? || counts[s].zero?)
  return unless (counts[p] > 0 && counts[s] >= 0)

  # Consider case where addition of fours[fours_offset] creates combination

if $debug    
  puts "Case of selecting fours[#{fours_offset}] = #{fours[fours_offset]}"
end
  
  if n == 1
if $debug    
    puts "Since n == 1 append #{fours_selected + [fours_offset]} to $combinations"
end
    $combinations << (fours_selected + [fours_offset])

puts "$combinations.size = #{$combinations.size}" if $combinations.size % 1_000_000 == 0

  else
if $debug    
    puts "Since n > 1 call enumerate_tail"
end
    enumerate_tail(n-1, counts.merge(p=>counts[p]-1, s=>counts[s]-1),
      fours, fours_selected + [fours_offset], fours_offset+1)
if $debug    
    puts "\nBack in $i = #{$i}"
end  
  end
if $debug    
  puts "Returning from $i = #{$i}"
end  
  $i -= 1
end
```

Comment: Many, many thanks for this. I will do my best to get around to studying it and understanding it as soon as I can. Unfortunately, my car has developed an emissions fault so I really need to get that fixed. :(

Comment: How long did this take to run for you? (for some reason this won't let me @ anyone...)

Comment: fuzzy, I've reworked the recursion and run it with your data set. The results were a pleasant surprise.

Comment: This is looking very promising. I'm working on converting it to PHP now. Sorry for not being on the ball. I got hit with Norovirus. Many thanks indeed for this. I aim to get back to you within the next few days to accept this as the answer.

Comment: Fuzzy, I look forward to hearing if it works for you.

Comment: Cary, This works really well, although it takes over an hour to run on my machine, but that's still very good, all things considered. According to ruby-prof, it uses about 21GB of memory. Since I only have 16GB, I suspect that there was a lot of paging involve, which would explain why it takes so long for me to run it. Many, many thanks again for this, and sorry it took so long for me to finally get back to you.